# Calculate a particular product from all sales

Tags: sql-server

How is the total income from from product A caculated?
and is the solution to the question correct?

question:
Monthly table of 2010
Month, number of unique customers who bought, number of products, total income, total income from product A (only about 2010).

[image: Sample Data]

```
SELECT MONTH (Date) AS SaleMonth,
           COUNT (DISTINCT CustomerID) AS CustomerCount,   
           COUNT (ProductID) AS ProductCount,
           SUM (Income) AS TotalIncome

FROM table a
WHERE YEAR (Date) = '2010'
GROUP BY MONTH (Date) AS SaleMonth
```

Comment: Posting images of technical information like sample data, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen for a question to be downvoted and closed or ignored.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, clauses like `WHERE YEAR (Date) = '2010'` perform very poorly; use date boundaries.

Comment: Your where clause seems to be missing a predicate. You stated you only want Product A from the year 2010. Given your sample data and stated requirements this should only find a single row in your table.

Comment: _"Is the solution correct"_ - no idea. You should test this yourself. If you don't have a MySQL instance to test on there are plenty of online services you can use. Try http://db-fiddle.com, for example

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear what exactly you need as result.

Let it be so: number of unique `CustomerId`s, count of `ProductId`s (not unique as far as i understand), total income and total income of product `A`, all is grouped per month of 2010.

In this case your query would be like this:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(Date) as Month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) as CustomerCount, 
    COUNT(ProductId) as ProductCount, 
    SUM(IIF(ProductId = 'A', Income, 0)) as TotalIncomeA, 
    SUM(Income) as TotalIncome
FROM t
WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2010
GROUP BY MONTH(Date)
```

You can check it https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=599406fc60799c3975beeb4e99e78d3e